# How do I make cookie sessions?

Tags: django

I'm trying to make a cookie session and can't find anything thats resembles clear documentation. The django docs on this are very weak!

Alls I found was this guys video on cookies: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U_dDY7TvJ4E

Can someone show me how to make a cookie when a visitor goes to my site?

I want be able to save that cookie in my database, so that when they make another request I can associate changes with them server side.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the link for where in the Django Docs on how to make cookies:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/

A short example of how to do so would be like so.  You can use the built in `Session` table as a `dictionary` like so:

```
def myView(request):
  request.session['foo'] = 'bar'
  # other view code
  render(request, 'mypage.html')
```

**UPDATE:**

This is how you would redirect a User based on if they have a `Cookie` or not

```
def myViewTwo(request):
  id = request.session['UUID1']
  # verify the UUID1 exists
  if id == 'UUID1:
    return render(request, 'cookie.html')
  # if not, send them to a normal view
  return render(request, 'no_cookie.html')
```

Comment: I suppose you can check to see if the session exists as well?

Comment: What do I replace foo and bar with? I assign foo bar. Does that mean foo is the user or session, and or bar is the user? is that then stored in the cookie or do I take bar or foo and store that into the cookie?

Comment: That worked for me btw! I just need to know how to make foo and abr work

Comment: You can replace "Foo" and "Bar" with any information that you want.  It works like any other Python Dictionary object.  I saves the data to the Django Built-in Session table under that User's Session.

Comment: request.session['UUID1'] = 'UUID1' When the visitor goes to my site I get the UUID1 from his cookies and if it doesn't match than no go, but if it does than I can associate stuff with the user in the database? Either the foo or bar are stored in the cookie, and I use it to check if the person is who they are and to link it to some data associated with them in the database?